Get list of unique words without numbers and symbols from paragraph range in Google Sheet?
I have list of comments in Google sheet which is sourced from Google form. It is difficult for me to list down each unique words from lots of paragraph.
I have already tested this function which provided from here: How to get a list of unique unknown words from a google sheet
=ArrayFormula(unique(transpose(split(concatenate("|"&A:Z),"|"))))

However, it does not work at all. I have attached the picture which is using the formula, and does not meet my expectation.
The list of unique words:


Consider providing input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

You can try this formula:
=UNIQUE(TOCOL(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(" ",A2:A6), "[\d\W]+", " ")," ")))

Sample Output:

Reference:
Regular Expression

It works. Nicely done @Alma_Matters. Thank you for your help.
